# How to convert <class 'UnitsNet.Ratio'> to a float type number for calculations?

Tags: c#, units-of-measurement

When I call a function via my company's API, I get a result which looks like a float number - for example `0.38`

However, the type of these numbers are Ratio objects with the type UnitsNet.Ratio. I cannot multiply these values together, this is the error message I get when I try to do so:

> **TypeError: No method matches given arguments for op_Multiply: (<class 'UnitsNet.Ratio'>)**

This is what I can see in the _*init*.py file for the API:

```
**@property
    def LoadAnalyse(self) -> Ratio:**
```

Could anyone let me know how to convert the Ratio object into a floating number? I have tried converting it into a float, but I get the following error message:

> **TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Ratio'**

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert an object to a primitive type like that, unless it represents a primitive type, then the **repr** function in it's python class would maybe work. Check the documentation and check if that class has a function or public member that gets the primitive representation as either a float, or string to parse.